# ActiveX Radio Buttons Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

On my main excel page I have two ActiveX control radio buttons called OptionButton1 and OptionButton2 I would like to use for a Yes/No option.

In my code I have the following:

```
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    MsgBox "Yes."
ElseIf OptionButton2.Value = True Then
    MsgBox "No."
End If
```

When I try to run my macro I get this error:

```
Runtime error '424':
Object Required
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to reference where the option buttons are, i.e. on which sheet:

```
If Sheet1.OptionButton1.Value  Then ...
```

This is because (I assume) your code is not on that sheet, so un-referenced objects will be assumed to be on the *current* sheet, which may not be the right one.

Comment: +1 Objects/Controls shouldn't float around... should they? `Explicit Reference` is my friend ;)

Answer (score 0):

you may use the form controls option buttons instead and your code may look like

```
Dim Shp1 As Shape
Dim Shp2 As Shape

Dim Res As Integer   'Retuns the result
On Error Resume Next
Set Shp1 = Worksheets("sheet1").Shapes("Option Button 1")
Set Shp2 = Worksheets("sheet1").Shapes("Option Button 2")
   If Shp1 Is Nothing Then
    If Shp2 Is Nothing Then
        'MsgBox "none" 'in case they were deleted off the sheet
        Res = -3 '2 options deleted
    ElseIf Shp2.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
        'MsgBox "second"
        Res = 2
    Else
        'MsgBox "Only Button 2 exists and it is off"
        Res = -1 'Option Button1 deleted
    End If
Else
    If Shp1.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
        'MsgBox "first"
        Res = 1
    Else
        If Shp2 Is Nothing Then
            'MsgBox "Only Button 1 exists and it is off"
            Res = -2 'Option Button2 deleted
        ElseIf Shp2.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
            'MsgBox "sec"
            Res = 2
        Else
            'MsgBox "Both exists, both are off"
            Res = 0
        End If
    End If
End If
return Res
```